# How to Model a FACT-TABLE with Dynamic collection of value from DIMENSION table

Tags: database, database-design, dimensional-modeling

For this example we can consider "Uber-Accident" fact table.
If there is an accident fact, there will be one-driver and multiple riders ( in context of RIDE sharing ). Since traditional OLAP Data warehouse does not support structures like Maps how would design such a fact table ?

Most of the example in the Ralph-Kimball book are for static-groups , like Multiple-account holders , or multiple diagnosis in a fact. However they are all static "Dimension Bridge Group"

Is there a better way than a dimension-bridge-group to solve this problem in DW ( Like Vertica. Teradata ) where there is no Map structure ?

### DIM_DRIVER

DRIVER_SK

DRIVER_NAME

### DIM_RIDER

RIDER_SK

RIDER_NAME

### FACT_ACCIDENT

ACCIDENT_ID_DD

DRIVER_SK

HOW to add multiple riders ???

Comment: This is many-to-many relationship, and you're going to need an [associative table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) to bind riders to accidents.

Comment: Hi - can you clarify what your issues are with  a dimension-bridge-group that means you are looking for a better solution i.e. what is you definition of "better"?

Comment: @NickW If there are million accidents then there could be 5 million riders ... so the name Dimension-bridge is misnomer , then it becomes a fact .. since Fact to Fact join is not good .. I have to create fact_accident_details and then make it look like ... accident_dd, driver_id .. so when needed I can do a drill-across ... However I don't want an additional FACT table ... if the DW is on lake, then I can use MAP struct and store in Parquet to ORC .. In Redshift or Vertica I don't have MAP struct .. so my dilemma is between FACT_ACCIDENT_DETAIL vs Bridge-Dimension ...

Comment: I'm not sure where you think a second fact table comes from/why it is necessary? You have a Riders dimension with all your Riders and a Riders-Group table with keys for RiderGroup and Rider. When you add a record to the accident fact you generate a new RiderGroup key, populate the fact table with this and add records to the Riders-Group table, 1 per Rider, with the RiderGroup SK and the Rider SK

Comment: @NickW In terms of record-count, the  Riders-Group-Bridge-Dimension table has more records than the Accident-fact table ... so should it be called Fact-Riders-Group ?? Dimensions are supposed to be smaller than Facts ...

Comment: Its not a dimension table, its a bridge table - they're not the same thing

Comment: thanks @NickW ... it makes sense ...